# On click of an icon, Open a popping text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On a click of an `font-awesome` icon, I want to open a text area which pops up a little.

Here's how my HTML looks like

```
<div class="profile-div">
 <div class="header">
  <img src="assets/images/image.png" alt=""><h3 ></h3>
   <a href="#" class="bttn3">Edit Profile</a>
 </div>
 <p>Add a description about your self.. 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
 </p>
</div>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5efcokhq/4/) for the same. On click of the pencil icon, I want a text area to pop up a bit, maybe just like it happens on the facebook.

Comment: What did you've tried so far? Show us your code of js please.

Comment: Check the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5efcokhq/5/

Comment: Add some css so that it looks like a popup to it

Comment: @PatrickMlr

`$( ".textflied-popup" ).click(function() {
      $('.textflied-popup-wrapper').css('display','block');
  });
  $( ".close_text_pop").click(function() {
      $('.textflied-popup-wrapper').css('display','none');
  });`


Here's just the JS which I was trying If this satisfies you SIR

Comment: @SurajShukla Please add this to your question. So everyone will see this.

Comment: I didn't want to confuse others and hence I didn't put what I am trying.

Comment: check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

After anchor tag add a span like `<span id="spanId" style="display: none">Text</span>` and give an id for the icon tag. Then use the `toggle()`.

`$('#iconTagId').click(function(){$('#spanId').toggle();});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this html :

make sure that use jquery.js and bootstrap.js in bootom of the page

```
 <p>Add a description about your self.. 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
 </p>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Signature</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label style="padding-left: 0px;" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    Enter Email
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="txtVerifyEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" />

            </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnverifydismiss" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use modals.

Answer (score 0):

Give id or class name to your anchor tag, like

```
<a href="#" id="editPencil"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

After anchor tag, you add the textarea in your html code as following

```
<div class="form-group" id="comment" style="display:none;">
     <textarea class="form-control" id="commentBox"></textarea>
</div>
```

And in your script, use the following JQuery function. So on click of the pencil icon, you can open a text area

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#editPencil").click(function(){
        $("#comment").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS only solution**

A simple toggle logic can be build just playing with some styles and hidden checkbox and styled label:

HTML

```
<label for="checkbox">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BdHAZdS.png" alt="">
</label>

<input id="toggle" type="checkbox"/>
<p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add a description about your self.."> 
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</p>
```

CSS

```
.toggle-button {
    // Button styles go here
}    
#checkbox {
    display: none;
}
#checkbox:checked + p {
    display: block;
}
```

**Link:** [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5efcokhq/13/)

Comment: Can't you see the main idea?) It doesn't make any difference. Paste your image inside a label tag and the magic will happen!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there's a backend logic, but here's what you should do for the front-end:

https://jsfiddle.net/jqr1L2Lh/

HTML:

```
<div class="profile-div">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BdHAZdS.png" alt="">
        <h3></h3>
        <a href="#" class="bttn3">Edit Profile</a>
    </div>
    <p><span>Add a description about your self..</span>
        <a id='edit-button' href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="popup">
    <label>Edit the description</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button>Done</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit-button').click(function() {
        $('div.popup').show();
        $('div.popup textarea').val($('div.profile-div p>span').html());
    });
    $('div.popup button').click(function() {
        $('div.profile-div p>span').html($('div.popup textarea').val());
        $('div.popup').hide();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.popup {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I see nothing happening in your fiddle

Answer (score -1):

Ok here is what I came up with. Is should help you to get started. I have only added 2 classes to your code and controlled them via jQuery.

```js
$('#showbox').on('click', function(){
  $('.profile-div').toggleClass('popup');
  $('body').toggleClass('showPopup');
})
```

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .2s;
}



.profile-div-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    padding-top: 97px;
}
.profile-div {
  margin: 5% auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
/*     float: left; */
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px 15px 40px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all .2s ease;
  
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.profile-div .header {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.profile-div .header h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 33px;
}

.profile-div .header a.bttn3 {
    float: right;
    line-height: 34px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #673a9a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.profile-div p {
    color: #646464;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.profile-div p a {
    color: #646464;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.fa-pencil:before {
    content: "\f040";
}
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.popup{
  background: #f4f4f4;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.showPopup{
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="profile-div">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BdHAZdS.png" alt="">
    <h3></h3>
    <a href="#" class="bttn3">Edit Profile</a>
  </div>
  <p>Add a description about your self..
    <a href="#" id="showbox"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
  </p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @SurajShukla can you explain more?

Comment: when I click the icon, `Add a description about your self..` should pop up and it should become a textfield/textarea

Comment: http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/MboazE check the updated fiddle. The area is editable . Also why don't you just put a textarea in place of p?

Comment: It is covering the whole div, I want just `p` to be the textfield.

Comment: I am not using textfield because I do not want it to be editable from the word go. I want it to be editable on icon click

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128909/discussion-between-hunzaboy-and-suraj-shukla).